# Python program to write other programs

Tags: python

Could this be a possibility? Could you develop a program to write a program for you inside of the already existing program? Then save the program the program has written to a .py file and execute it as if it where the user?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Your Question should be "How" and show us what you tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any string in a python program can be run as a python script.

```
>>> python_script="print('hello autogenerated world')"
>>> exec(python_script)
hello autogenerated world
```

So you could generate a script as a string, save it to a file, the load it into a string and run it with `exec` .

How to generate the script though, I think is a question that will require some knowledge of AI(neural networks)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, but to create such program, you need to have excellent knowledge on programming and on many more things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You could write the text to a file through the normal process and then run the execfile command. There are probably better ways to do it, but that one just came to mind.